# Django: add field to a ModelForm in CreateVView.form_valid

Tags: django-generic-views, django-forms

I have users creating lists in my site and I'm using the generic CreateView to allow them create them. One of the fields of a list is the owner (who creates it).

It does not make sense to ask users to select the owner, since the user that is creating it is already the owner.

So, I'm passing to the CreateView a "form_class" instead of a "model" parameter where the form_class excludes the owner field.

In order to save the form, I need to add the owner to it.

I subclassed CreateView and added a form_valid method, but I'm having problems doing this.

So far, I got

```
class MyCreateView(CreateView)
    form_class = ListForm

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.??? = self.request.user -->> expression of the left side
    return super(MyCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

It should be something simple. In [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/f8a9832dcb5e9e87), they say to use `self.object.owner`, but  self.object is a `None` type.

How should I handle this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `form.instance.owner = request.user` and then call super

Comment: I'm using pdb just after the form_valid is called. self.instance returns "DoesNotExist" and self.instance returns AttributeError: 'MyCreateView' object has no attribute 'instance'. ListForm is also a ModelForm

Comment: I added form.instance = MyModel() and then form.instance.owner = self.request.user. THis apprently works, but when the model is saved to the db, all fields in the displayed form are empty.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, i needed to do if form.is_valid(): form.instance.owner = request.user